# Where can I find high quality mock-ups?

Tags: resource-recommendations, mockup

I see a lot of graphic designer showing their work with really creative and professional mock-ups. Most of the websites I look have few good mock-up such as: http://graphicburger.com/

Do you know any website with really high quality, high resolution, creative mock-ups for showing my work?

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find a duplicate question for this

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't closed as it will produce spam answers, answers that will not last over time and since the answers will be link only.  So far most of the answers are flagged as spam.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I downvoted it, and am seemingly the only to have done so. Wasn't going to close unless some of the community felt the same

Answer (score 0):

Behance has ton of good mock-ups

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of free resources (including mock-ups) on these websites:

http://makerbook.net/

https://resourcecards.com/

Answer (score 0):

[**FreeDesignResources**](http://freedesignresources.net/category/free-mockups/) — Has lots of free resources, including a wide selection of mockups, and is updated regularly.

[**GraphicRiver**](https://graphicriver.net/category/graphics/product-mock-ups) — Part of Envato Market — has lots of very reasonably priced resources, including a very large selection of product mockups, mostly priced between $5 – $10.

Answer (score 0):

[Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/home) is probably the industry standard. Though if you really want a consistent high quality set of mockups it is probably best to make them yourself. Take some pictures with blank papers/books or whatever you need and mock them up in photoshop, render them in 3D or even better photograph the real end result.